# Could not find gen_kernel.dart.snapshot

Tags: dart

I run a comman `dart compile aot-snapshot`, and found out `Could not find C:\Users\sony\Downloads\dartsdk-windows-ia32-release\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\gen_kernel.dart.snapshot. Have you built the full Dart SDK?`

is there any problem regarding my dart sdk ??

what should i do ?